# Closed set and Open set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

**EXERCISE** Show that $F$ is closed set $\iff$ if for all ball centered at $x$ contains points in $F$, then $x\in F$.

Thanks by your replies.

---

**DEFINITION** Given a metric space $(X,\rho)$ and a point $x$, an open ball about $x$ with radius $\epsilon$ is the set $B(x,\epsilon)=\{y\in X:\rho(x,y)<\epsilon\}$

**DEFINITION** Given a metric space $(X,\rho)$ and a point $x$ in $X$, a set $N$ is a neighborhood of $x$ if it contains an open ball about $x$.

**DEFINITION** Given a metric space $(X,\rho)$ and a subset $O$ of $X$, $O$ is open if it is a neighborhood of each of its points.

**DEFINITION** Given a metric space $(X,\rho)$ and a subset $F$ of $X$, $F$ is closed if it is a $X\setminus F$ is open.

Comment: What definition of closed set are you using?

Comment: a set is closed if that complement is open

Comment: @Juan What is your definition of an open set?

Comment: I do not understand the statement in the question (after *if for*).

Comment: Dear Juan look  at the definitions of open and closed sets you are using and you will easily figure it out. Don't mind the downvoted you had on your post. People are a bit bitter here.

Comment: I agree that the downvotes were a bit rash in this case (I did not downvote, for the record). But you should make sure to add a definition of what you understand as "closed" and "open" sets, when asking "low level" questions such as this one.

Comment: @Juan Are those definitions I added the ones you're using?

Comment: @checkmath Your *People are a bit bitter here* is odd. Please do not equate each and every downvote with the effect of a kind of moral perversity, some questions ARE badly phrased and DESERVE downvotes (ditto for answers), this is how the system works. (In case you are wondering, my only vote on this page is +1 to Alex Becker's comment.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be a metric space.

Suppose $F$ is closed. Suppose $x \notin F$. Then $x \in X - F$. Since $X - F$ is open, $x$ is an interior point. There exists a ball $B$ containing $x$ such that $B \subset X - F$. Hence $B$ does not contain points of $F$.

Suppose $F$ is not closed. Then $X - F$ is not open. Thus there exists a point $x \in X - F$ which is not an interior point. That is, every ball $B$ containing $x$ is not completely contained in $X - F$. Hence there is a point $x$ such that every ball containing $x$ intersects $F$ but $x \notin F$.

Comment: @tomasz He used the term ball so I assumed it was a metric space. I should probably remove the parenthetical remark, but I just wanted to mention that the result holds for general topological space if ball is replace by open set.